"Largest snake to ever live discovered in an Indian mine." VS "Largest snake to have ever lived ......"?
This is a title from a scientific magazine about how various animals lived on earth thousands of years ago. Here is the title:
Largest snake to ever live discovered in an Indian mine. Wildlife magazine
The structure "...to ever live..." caught my attention, because the title is clearly telling about animals that lived long long ago.
So, I would have thought "....to have ever lived ...." would follow to emphasize the past, but as you can see, the verb (live) is in the present form in the title.
Why is that? Is it because the next verb (discover) is in the past already?

The tense of the next verb is irrelevant. But just for the sake of it, here's a usage chart showing that 250 years ago it was always to have ever discovered, whereas today it's just to ever discover.

Titles are often not grammatical sentences, words are deliberately omitted to keep them short.

FumbleFingers and Barmar are wholly correct. Headlines - like titles - follow different rules than normal language.
Other options might include 'Largest snake ever to live…' or '… ever to have lived…'
In normal  grammar that's debatable until the cows come home. In headlines, titles and the like, it's debatable until the end of days.

"To have ever lived" would be an good alternative.  The perfect aspect would work well here. But in a headline, the shorter form may have been preferred.
The verb "live" is not in a present tense form, it is an infinitive and has no tense, so it could be used about past or non-past.  A perfect infinitive is possible but not required.

It's somewhat questionable, and I prefer the present perfect as well, but it's not wrong. You might understand it as following "It was the largest snake...", where the simple past seems to license the bare infinitive a bit better.
That said, the word order they've chosen for the infinitive sucks either way. Here's how I would write it:

largest snake ever to have lived


Perhaps you're just a bit behind the times. See this usage chart, showing that 200 years ago it was almost always to have ever existed, but today to ever live and to ever exist have almost completely eclipsed the "perfect infinitive" versions.

@FumbleFingers Although I'm no dogmatist about split infinitives, I do find it pretty ugly in the case of "ever". The data is mixed when you expand the terms. https://tinyurl.com/ever-to-ever

It seems pretty clear from this chart that it was nearly always ever to live until the "split infinitive" to ever live caught on over recent decades. Time to boldly take the language forward! :)
